# TOTAL NO. of ITERATIONS REACHED LIMIT in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, mediapipe

I want to load the pose and the movement from the csv data by using pandas. But when I want to load the data, I always get this error message:

```
C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_logistic.py:765: ConvergenceWarning: lbfgs failed to converge (status=1):
STOP: TOTAL NO. of ITERATIONS REACHED LIMIT.

Increase the number of iterations (max_iter) or scale the data as shown in:
    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html
Please also refer to the documentation for alternative solver options:
    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression
  extra_warning_msg=_LOGISTIC_SOLVER_CONVERGENCE_MSG)
```

As I understand it means that the lbfgs algorithm did not converge, because the maximum number of iterations has been reached. How can I solve the problem in code? I am new in python and scikit so am a little lost as to what I can do to improve it.

Comment: That's a scikit-learn thing, not a Python thing as such.

Answer (score 2):

This depends significantly on your data. The regression solver is telling you that it can't solve the problem you've given it, based on the data you've provided. You can try increasing the value of `max_iter` and see if that fixes it. But oherwise, I'd recommend normalising all of your data onto the interval 0-1 and trying again. In my experience regression solvers become innaccurate/unstable when working with very very large/small numbers in the same calculation. It will have the best chance of working well on a more manageable interval, like 0-1.

But without seeing the data I can't help any more than this.

Comment: Thx. These is a example how my csv data looks liekt `class,x1,y1,z1,v1,x2,y2,z2,v2,x3,y3,z3,v3,x4,y4,z4,v4,x5,y5,z5,v5,x6,y6,z6,v6 ... v21` `A,0.06512664258480072,0.7851656079292297,-0.000116509705549106,0.13680896162986755,0.7508699297904968,-0.037941571325063705,0.19306087493896484,0.6903841495513916,-0.060293059796094894,0.2164439558982849,0.6303356885910034,-0.08208338171243668,0.21190279722213745, 0.6385542750358582,-0.041343048214912415 ...0.6838412284851074,-0.13765662908554077`. So it goes on. There are 5096 rows in total.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't particularly helpful, without a reproducible example of your issue I don't think we can help you any further, besides recommending you try normalisation, which fixes common issues I've come across in the past